# new to scripting I'm looking to give permissions to folders I have to multiple individual users via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions

what I need to do is lets say I have 100 users and I need to give them rights to folders that I have on my google drive each person will have there own folder that only they can see and I can see .... so I would create a folder for bob called work and I need to give him rights to the folder same for sue etc. bob and sue can not see each others work folder but I can see it

the only thing I can find close is

```
function SetRights() {
    var folder = DriveApp.createFolder('WORK');
    folder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT)
}
```

but the folders are all-ready created and I don't want to give rights to the whole domain.

Comment: You should use the `getFoldersByName()` method for pre-existing folders: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFoldersByName(String), then set the permissions.

Comment: For `setSharing()` you can specify a class of users rather than the whole domain: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#setSharing(Access,Permission)

Comment: You can also use `addEditors()` and `addViewers()` (singular or plural) for specific email addresses: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addeditorsemailaddresses

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch an existing folder using [`DriveApp.getFoldersByName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFoldersByName(String)) to return a [`FolderIterator`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator). Loop over the folders to add viewer(s) and editor(s) to each folder with the [`folder.addEditor()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addeditorsemailaddresses) and [`folder.addViewer()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addvieweremailaddress) methods.

```
function AddUsersToFolder() {
    // get folders (FolderIterator) by name, should probably be dynamic
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('FOLDERNAME');
    // loop over all the folders
    while (folders.hasNext()) {
        // get the current folder from the iterator
        var folder = folders.next();
        // add viewer(s) and editor(s), should also be dynamic
        folder.addEditor('editor@domain.com');
        folder.addViewer('viewer@domain.com');
    }
}
```

Comment: when I do something like this                                                          function AddUsersToFolder() {
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Work'); 
  folder.addEditor('FirstName.LasName@Company.com');
}

I get a error ..... TypeError: Cannot find function addEditor in object FolderIterator. (line 3, file "Test")

Comment: Sorry about that - the `getFoldersByName()` method actually returns a `FolderIterator` which you will need to loop over to get each individual folder - I've updated the answer.

Comment: If you know the ID of the folder you can use [`getFolderById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid) instead to return a single `Folder` rather than a `FolderIterator` and avoid the loop.

Comment: its doing just what i need Thanks for the help :)

Comment: is there anyway to stop it from sending an email notification?